# Problem during system partial update. Can the system be recovered?

Tags: data-recovery

The system was undertaking a partial update when the screen/session logged off due to inactivity.
When attempted to log in, the system wouldn´t let me write the password.
The computer was then re-started.
When the system restarted, it showed the Windows (make of the laptop) and the Ubuntu logo, the next screen should have been the log in screen but instead it showed a blank screen that says: "A problem has occurred and the system can´t recover. Please contact a system administrator."
I tried restarting the computer again with the same outcome. Seems to be staring up normal and then, instead of the login screen, the white screen stating a problem has accurred appears.

I attach a picture of the error message.

Can I recover my data?[Message shown when laptop started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoYWZ.jpg)

Comment: Why was the system "*undertaking a partial update*?" And what exactly does that mean? A "partial update" (to us) usually refers to an incomplete release-upgrade or dist-upgrade. Those are very bad news, and can sometimes leave your system unbootable.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question regarding the recovery of the data, I would think you would be able to boot using a USB stick with the Live media on it and then mount the drive and recover your data that way.  Go to the Ubuntu website and follow the instructions for creating the bootable media and then modify your computer to boot from the USB device.  Then select the Try option and once you have booted to the desktop browse to the drive using Files.  This should allow you to mount and recover the files.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Ori_Bari - If this answered your question, could you accept the answer?  Thanks!